# Drag & Drop TableView Cell to Tapkus Calendar

Tags: iphone, ios, drag-and-drop, tapku

I have added the calendars in scrollview using tapkus library on the left. I want to drag the cell from right and if i put it on a date then it should be added in that date. The problem is i m able to drag the cell to a date but i m not able to know to which date i am adding.Here is my image.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi , Can you provided me some help , how to integrated or implement the calendar (calendars in scrollview using tapkus library). ?

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/65213224/CalDemo%202.zip Download the code from this url i hope it helps u

Answer (score 1):

If you dragging a view with date to another object than you can set view tag as date.

If I am not right can you elaborate your question?